# Operator comparison in an *ngIf

Tags: angular

I want to compare number in an ngIf and depending on the result i'll display something.

```
  <div>
      <div *ngIf="number(user.number)>59">
     {{  number(user.number) }}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="number(user.number)<60">
        {{  number(user.number) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

my number.ts

```
 number ( date: Date) {
    const now = new Date().getFullYear()
    const diff = Math.abs(now - new Date(date).getFullYear())
    console.log(diff)
    return diff 
}
```

it will return a number

This is not working i think there's a problem with ">" & "<" operator, is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: what is number() in component.ts

Comment: it will return a number ( difference between two dates )

Comment: The operators are correct. Check the calculated difference, I guess that is wrong.

Comment: plz provide your type script code.

Comment: @Faisal it's returning me a number

Comment: @KrishnaRathore check question

Comment: Tell me a sample `user.number` value.

Comment: remove function keyword in ts file

Comment: thank you @KrishnaRathore it solved my problem by removing the function keyword

Comment: this answer does not deserve down vote

Answer (score 0):

the interior of `*ngIf` (value between `""`) must end up in being evaluable to truthy/false value. The issue might be in your `number()` implementation, usages of `>` & `<` are perfectly fine.

Please provide your function implementation and wider context i.e. from where `user.number` comes from

--EDIT--
After OP posted TS code, there will be issue with date format. The part:
 `new Date(date).getFullYear()` in case of incorrect value will evaluate to 1970, then result will be always 48, which is less than both values compared. You need to validate your input in date creation.

Try in browser console to create any of following:

```
new Date(99)
new Date(2000)
new Date(20)
```

they will all evaluate to `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100`.
Supplement Date constructor with dummy parameter:

```
new Date(99, 0)
new Date(2000, 0)
new Date(20, 0)
```

to get valid dates. But still, this is just an assumption, since you are not providing us format of `user.number`, i just assumed this is input text value in range 0 to infinity.

Comment: It will check the value in the database, and compare it, when i'm doing a console log it's working fine and returning me value, if i'm born in 1992 and compare the date, it will display me in console.log // 25 
My problem is in my ngIf didn't know how to properly use thecompare operator

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `moment`

install moment by - `npm install moment --save`

> app.component.html

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="number(user.number)>59">
        {{ number(user.number) }}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="number(user.number)<60">
        {{ number(user.number) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

> app.component.ts

```
import moment from 'moment';

number(date: Date) {
    const diff =Math.abs(moment().diff(moment(date),'year'))
    console.log(diff);
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question is not about moment.js