# how to implement comparator number in an *ngIf

Tags: angular

I want to compare number in an ngIf and depending on the result i'll display something.

```
  <div>
      <div *ngIf="dateNumber(user.date)>18">
     {{  dateNumber(user.date) }}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="dateNumber(user.date)<18">
        {{  dateNumber(user.date) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

my number.ts

```
 dateNumber ( date: Date) {
    const now = new Date().getFullYear()
    const diff = Math.abs(now - new Date(date).getFullYear())
    console.log(diff)
    return diff 
}
```

it will return a number, when i do a console log it will return me a number.

This is not working i think there's a problem with ">" & "<" operator, is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: Can you not use a function instead?

Comment: "number" is a reserver word, try rename your function as "edad" (but not use Math.abs). TIP: You can make your function return only true or false

Comment: @Eliseo did it still not working

Comment: @Eliseo Returning true or false, how can i get the number if i make it return true or false ?

Comment: this question is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439660/operator-comparaison-in-an-ngif?noredirect=1#comment89851917_51439660

Comment: @LisaN, Usually we want know if someone is of legal age, not the difference in years from now. If you need the difference of years, you're ok, you need return a number

Comment: @LisaN, can you tell the output of `user.date`?

Comment: @Eliseo yes i want to check the age and display it in the div

Comment: @AnkitSharma a number depending of the date of the user but the typeof the return is a number

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the argument sent inside `dateNumber` is of type `date` or `string` that could be converted to date.

You may use the below code if in case the date argument is not a valid date.

```
  dateNumber(date: Date) {
    const now = new Date().getFullYear();
    const diff = Math.abs(now - new Date(date).getFullYear());
    console.log(diff);
    if (isNaN(diff)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return diff;
    }
  }
```

For a running example, please refer to the below link:-

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5cofc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Hope it helps.